# .NET Core 3.1 Console Application hangs

Tags: .net-core, npgsql, .net-core-3.1

I have a .NET Core 3.1 console application that is running some background cron jobs. There are different jobs doing different things and they will start every x minute, do its thing and then stop. Most of the time they run fine, but lately these jobs have been starting to hang. They just never finish, the process is stuck.

I don't really know how to debug this or how to figure out what is causing it to hang. What I've done is:

- Create a `DMP` file from the task manager
- Load this using `dotnet dump analyze myfile.DMP`
- Run `dumpasync -stacks`

This gives a list of all the stacks. I've created a few `DMP` files from different workers (doing different things), but they all have in common that there is one task on `Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer`.

This is one example:

```
000001ed01aa18c8 00007ffca0c9e3d8      128          1 Npgsql.NpgsqlReadBuffer+<>c__DisplayClass34_0+<<Ensure>g__EnsureLong|0>d
Async "stack":
.000001ed01aa1988 (1) Npgsql.NpgsqlConnector+<>c__DisplayClass160_0+<<DoReadMessage>g__ReadMessageLong|0>d
..000001ed01aa1a40 (5) Npgsql.NpgsqlDataReader+<NextResult>d__44
...000001ed01aa1ae0 (0) Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand+<ExecuteReaderAsync>d__102
....000001ed01aa1b90 (0) Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand+<ExecuteDbDataReaderAsync>d__97
.....000001ed01aa1c10 (1) Dapper.SqlMapper+<QueryAsync>d__33`1[[System.__Canon, System.Private.CoreLib]]
......000001ed021ac5d8 (3) Acme.Common.Data.Dapper.Repositories.AccountItems.GetDapperAccountItemsHandlerSql+<GetAccountItemsAsync>d__3
.......000001ed021ac638 (0) Acme.Common.Data.Dapper.Repositories.ItemRepository`1+<GetAccountItemsHigherThanIdAsync>d__9[[Acme.Core.Db.Dapper.DapperReaderConnection, Acme.Core.Db.Dapper]]
........000001ed021ac698 (1) Acme.Common.Services.EmailReport.ReportDataService+<MakeInstantAlertDto>d__20
.........000001ed00badd90 (3) Acme.Common.Services.EmailReport.ReportDataService+<GetReportDtoAsync>d__19
..........000001ed0105f968 (2) Acme.Common.Services.EmailReport.InstantAlertReportService+<SendInstantAlertReportAsync>d__6
...........000001ed0105f9c8 (0) Acme.Common.Services.EmailReport.EmailReportWorkerService+<SendInstantAlertReportsAsync>d__10
............000001ed01b902d0 System.Threading.Tasks.TaskFactory+CompleteOnInvokePromise
```

I don't know if this means that `npgsql` is the cause of the hang, but it seems to be what is common between all of them.

The connection is created like this:

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<MyDto>> GetData()
{
    using (var dbConnection = await _dapperConnection.OpenAsync())
    {
        var sql = "SELECT * FROM ....";
        var result = await dbConnection.QueryAsync<MyDto>(sql);
        return result;
    }
}

private async Task<NpgsqlConnection> OpenAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
{
    var connection = new NpgsqlConnection(_connectionString);
    await connection.OpenAsync(cancellationToken);

    return connection;
}
```

The connection string looks like this:
`User ID=<userid>;Password=<password>;Host=<host>;Port=5432;Database=<databasename>;Pooling=true;Maximum Pool Size=200;Keepalive=30;`

How can I debug this further? What would help?

#### Further technical details

Npgsql version: 4.1.3

PostgreSQL version: 9.6

Operating system: Windows

Comment: Cross-posted as a github issue: https://github.com/npgsql/npgsql/issues/2884

Comment: Did you happen to solve this one? I'm having a similar problem with the latest Npgsql. My app can open a connection and start a transaction just fine, but then the DbCommand.ExecuteReaderAsync call just never returns, and I have no idea why.

Comment: @aoven See the linked issue above. I think we determined it was related to network issues. The connection would drop but npgsql had no idea of it and was stuck waiting.